# Feature detection with patent-free descriptors

Tags: algorithm, opencv, image-recognition, feature-detection, opencv3.0

I need the feature detection algorithm. I'm fed up surfing on the web finding nothing but SURF example and *hints* how to do that, but I did not find an example with other than patented descriptors like SIFT or SURF.

Can anybody write an example of using the **free** feature detection algorithm (like ORB/BRISK [as far as I understood SURF and FLAAN are **nonfree**]) ?

I'm using OpenCV 3.0.0.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Instead of using a SURF keypoint detector and descriptor extractor, just switch to use ORB. You can simply change the string passed to `create` to have different extractors and descriptors.

The following is valid for OpenCV 2.4.11.

[Feature Detector](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html?#featuredetector-create)

- "FAST" – FastFeatureDetector
- "STAR" – StarFeatureDetector
- "SIFT" – SIFT (nonfree module)
- "SURF" – SURF (nonfree module)
- "ORB" – ORB
- "BRISK" – BRISK
- "MSER" – MSER
- "GFTT" – GoodFeaturesToTrackDetector
- "HARRIS" – GoodFeaturesToTrackDetector with Harris detector enabled
- "Dense" – DenseFeatureDetector
- "SimpleBlob" – SimpleBlobDetector

[Descriptor Extractor](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_extractors.html#descriptorextractor-create)

- "SIFT" – SIFT
- "SURF" – SURF
- "BRIEF" – BriefDescriptorExtractor
- "BRISK" – BRISK
- "ORB" – ORB
- "FREAK" – FREAK

[Descriptor Matcher](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html#descriptormatcher-create)

- BruteForce (it uses L2 )
- BruteForce-L1
- BruteForce-Hamming
- BruteForce-Hamming(2)
- FlannBased

FLANN is not in *nonfree*. You can use other matchers, however, like `BruteForce`.

The example below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Mat img_object = imread("D:\\SO\\img\\box.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat img_scene = imread("D:\\SO\\img\\box_in_scene.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    if (!img_object.data || !img_scene.data)
    {
        std::cout << " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1;
    }

    //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
    Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = FeatureDetector::create("ORB");

    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

    detector->detect(img_object, keypoints_object);
    detector->detect(img_scene, keypoints_scene);

    //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = DescriptorExtractor::create("ORB");

    Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

    extractor->compute(img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object);
    extractor->compute(img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene);

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create("BruteForce");
    std::vector< DMatch > matches;
    matcher->match(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches);

    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
        if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
    }

    printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
    printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);

    //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
    std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        if (matches[i].distance < 3 * min_dist)
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
        }
    }

    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches(img_object, keypoints_object, img_scene, keypoints_scene,
        good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
        vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

    //-- Localize the object
    std::vector<Point2f> obj;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene;

    for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++)
    {
        //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
        obj.push_back(keypoints_object[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        scene.push_back(keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }

    Mat H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

    //-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
    std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
    obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0, 0); obj_corners[1] = cvPoint(img_object.cols, 0);
    obj_corners[2] = cvPoint(img_object.cols, img_object.rows); obj_corners[3] = cvPoint(0, img_object.rows);
    std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

    perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

    //-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

    //-- Show detected matches
    imshow("Good Matches & Object detection", img_matches);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

OpenCV 3.0.0 has a different API.

You can find a list of non-patented feature detector and descriptor extractor [here](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d51/group__features2d__main.html).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;

/** @function main */
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Mat img_object = imread("D:\\SO\\img\\box.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
    Mat img_scene = imread("D:\\SO\\img\\box_in_scene.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    if (!img_object.data || !img_scene.data)
    {
        std::cout << " --(!) Error reading images " << std::endl; return -1;
    }

    //-- Step 1: Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
    Ptr<FeatureDetector> detector = ORB::create();

    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_object, keypoints_scene;

    detector->detect(img_object, keypoints_object);
    detector->detect(img_scene, keypoints_scene);

    //-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    Ptr<DescriptorExtractor> extractor = ORB::create();

    Mat descriptors_object, descriptors_scene;

    extractor->compute(img_object, keypoints_object, descriptors_object);
    extractor->compute(img_scene, keypoints_scene, descriptors_scene);

    //-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors using FLANN matcher
    Ptr<DescriptorMatcher> matcher = DescriptorMatcher::create("BruteForce");
    std::vector< DMatch > matches;
    matcher->match(descriptors_object, descriptors_scene, matches);

    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
        if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
    }

    printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
    printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);

    //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
    std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

    for (int i = 0; i < descriptors_object.rows; i++)
    {
        if (matches[i].distance < 3 * min_dist)
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
        }
    }

    Mat img_matches;

    drawMatches(img_object, keypoints_object, img_scene, keypoints_scene, good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), std::vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);

    //-- Localize the object
    std::vector<Point2f> obj;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene;

    for (int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++)
    {
        //-- Get the keypoints from the good matches
        obj.push_back(keypoints_object[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        scene.push_back(keypoints_scene[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }

    Mat H = findHomography(obj, scene, CV_RANSAC);

    //-- Get the corners from the image_1 ( the object to be "detected" )
    std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);
    obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0, 0); obj_corners[1] = cvPoint(img_object.cols, 0);
    obj_corners[2] = cvPoint(img_object.cols, img_object.rows); obj_corners[3] = cvPoint(0, img_object.rows);
    std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

    perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

    //-- Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene - image_2 )
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[0] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[1] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[2] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
    line(img_matches, scene_corners[3] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f(img_object.cols, 0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

    //-- Show detected matches
    imshow("Good Matches & Object detection", img_matches);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which OpenCV version are you using? This works ok in OpenCV 2.4.9, and 2.4.11

Comment: the latest one, which is available for iOS at opencv website.

Comment: No member named 'create' in 'cv::Feature2d'

Comment: @denis631 a few things changed in OpenCV 3.0.0. _Now_ the updated code will work!

Comment: AKAZE is another good one, its matching accuracy is close to SURF while its runtime performance is much like SIFT and a whole lot slower than ORB. http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/features2d/akaze_matching/akaze_matching.html

Comment: @SaharshBishnoi sure, there are a lot of new nice descriptors in OpenCV 3.0, including AKAZE. I added a link to the documentation in my answer.

Comment: you are awesome as always @Miki